Vitual host not working after adding the code in the apache2.conf file
I am trying to install SSL on my website but getting issues in the virtual host. I have added below code in /etc/apache2/apacha2.conf and saved it.
Now when I try to restart the Apache then I am getting the below error

Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with
error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl
-xe" for details.

<VirtualHost *:443>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ServerName example.com
                SSLEngine on
                SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/newssl/c42264bab5f4631.crt
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/newssl/example.com.key
                SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/newssl/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
</VirtualHost>


The content of /var/log/syslog should tell you exactly what the error is. When using SSL certificates, remember that they must have very specific permissions applied to them, otherwise they will not be trusted by Apache.

Check the logs at /var/log/syslog as matigo and update your question. You can also share the output of journalctl -xe

@matigo, can I know what permission you are talking about?

I refer to file permissions. For example, an SSL key file with 777 permissions will always be rejected as it means that anything can change it at any time, not just the system administrator. Apache has strict requirements for any files that are used by the mod_ssl package.

@matigo, I have checked journalctl -xe details and found I found error "Apache: Invalid command 'SSLEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration"

I have solved this using command "sudo a2enmod SSL"
